# Store values into object of object through SQL Query using linq to entity

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have two sql table and two class as below.

```cs
public class StateMaster
{
    public long StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}

public class CityMaster
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public long CityId { get; set; }
    public  StateMaster objStateMaster { get; set;}
}
```

I can store City Master data into `CityMaster` object but how can i store State Master data into `City Master` object as `objStateMaster` object already created into `City Master` class.

```cs
List<CityMaster> objCityMaster = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<CityMaster>(
$@"select 
    CM.CityName,
    CM.CityId
from CityMaster CM
left join StateMaster SM
    On SM.StateId= CM.StateId").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create a new class called `StateCityMaster` as the follow:

```cs
public class StateCityMaster
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public long CityId { get; set; }
    public long StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

than edit the query as:

```
List<StateCityMaster> objStateCityMaster = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<StateCityMaster>(
$@"select 
    CM.CityName,
    CM.CityId,
    SM.StateId,
    SM.StateName
from CityMaster CM
left join StateMaster SM
    On SM.StateId= CM.StateId").ToList();
```

then create the list of `CityMaster` objects and copy values:

```
List<CityMaster> citiesMaster = new List<CityMaster>();

objStateCityMaster.forEach(scm => citiesMaster.Add(new CityMaster()
{
    CityName = scm.CityName;
    CityId = scm.CityId;
    objStateMaster.StateId = scm.StateId;
    objStateMaster.StateName = scm.StateName;
}));
```

Comment: We can do but it's not wise advice. I have many relational table in my actual query, Just share simple two table question due to help better understand.